# Number of Access Ports

Tags: cubesat

I am currently developing a 3U CubeSat and following the [Design specifications Rev. 13](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5418c831e4b0fa4ecac1bacd/t/56e9b62337013b6c063a655a/1458157095454/cds_rev13_final2.pdf). there are 3 access ports. Must I provide 3 access ports or 1 access port in one of the locations defined by the specifications?

Comment: From what I can tell, the only thing you absolutely must provide is the RBF pin. All other connectors are optional, but they must be in one of the specified access port locations.

Answer (score 2):

The access ports are the only locations where you can access the surface of your CubeSat when it is inside the CubeSat dispenser. You have to include an RBF pin to cut power from the system thru integration into the dispenser, and it has to be in one of the access ports regions. You don't have to include other connectors, but if you do, they need to be in an access ports regions or they won't be accessible after integration into the CubeSat dispenser.